# How can I fix excel appearance in cognos ?

Tags: excel, cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi, cognos-tm1

I make a report as pdf.It s fine. But when I export it to excel ,there are many sheets on excel . I do not wan to it.I want to 1 sheet.How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your Cognos version you can use the Excel 2000 single sheet format in Cognos 8.X: 
[Cognos 8.4.1 Excel Formats](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/c8bi/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_cra.8.4.0.doc/ug_cra_id28123ModifyingtheCognosReportViewerStyleSheets.html) 
However, I assume you are using Cognos 10.X. In this version this feature is deprecated:
[Excel 2000 and Excel 2000 Single Sheet Report Outputs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r2m0/topic/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_pps.10.2.0.doc/c_rs_deprecated_excel_2000.html?path=4_1_1_3_0#rs_deprecated_excel_2000) 
So, you can use the following options:
1. Export report in CSV or Excel 2007 Data format. This is excellent choice if format is not required. 
2. Change your report layout to support single sheet excel: Create all your report objects in one page, remove any page sets definition. 
You can use render variable to create separate output for Excel and separate output for other formats.